# Is there any adjective synonymous to "to the point"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

Is there any adjective synonymous to "to the point"?

For example,

"Jack's and Jill's answers are quite **to-the-point**, but Mary's answer is the **most-to-the-point** one"

EDIT:

A better example:

Teacher: "Can anyone come up with a good logical syllogism proving that all humans need the Sun?"

Linda: "I got it! Here, in my encyclopedia page 345 says, 'All fish need water and the Sun' I think it's exactly what we need!"

Jack: "All humans need to live. The Sun doesn't live. So, all humans need the Sun"

Jill: "All humans like fish. Without the Sun, all fish will die. So, all humans will be sad without the Sun"

Mary: "Anything alive needs the Sun (otherwise, if there is no Sun, anything alive will die). All humans are alive. Thus, all humans need the Sun"

---

so, Jack's and Jill's answers are quite **to-the-point**, but Mary's answer is the **most-to-the-point** one

Comment: How about using 'precise'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely apposite is the word you want? And succinct means expressed both briefly and precisely, doesn't it? Etymologically, tightly delimited, as with a belt (It's a cinch).

Answer (score 13):

**[Relevant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/relevant)** and **[pertinent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pertinent)** are synonyms to that concept:

> Jack's and Jill's answers are quite relevant, but Mary's answer is the most apt.

**[Germane](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/germane)**, **[apt](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apt)**, **[suitable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suitable)**, and **[apropos](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apropos)** are some more.

If you desire still more synonyms, you could try [thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/pertinent).

Answer (score 7):

What about "[succinct](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/succinct)"?

This doesn't seem to fit with your second example, but it's what comes to mind when I think "to the point." Someone who digresses and takes their time answering is not to the point; they are not very succinct.

More in line with your examples, (but less, in my opinion, with "to the point") would be "[accurate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/accurate)".

It's hard to tell what you're looking for, because "to the point" doesn't seem like the appropriate phrase to describe the scenario in the example. "On target" is something I've heard in a teaching context like that.

Comment: Perhaps, I don't understand the real meaning of "to the point" then.

Comment: +1 for giving "succinct", which to me is a good synonym for 'to the point'

Comment: Isn't it like "succinct" would merely mean "concise"? In my example the first answer was almost like "out of another story" - she failed to provide a syllogism at all. The next two answers were better as they provided some syllogisms, but those syllogisms were not logically accurate. Only the last answer met both standarts.

Comment: @brilliant You're right, but as I said, I wouldn't use "to the point"ness to describe the progression of the students' answers. I offered two words: one for what I thought you *meant* and one for what you *said*. I would say that the last student's answer is the "most accurate", but I would also say that the best one-word replacement for "to the point" is "succinct". Does that help?